# Testing in Javascript while mocking/stubbing a Solidity smart contract function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, sinon, solidity

I am trying to test a function that makes an external call using sinon but I can't figure out how I can muck/stub a function inside it that tries to make an external call.

**Edit**
I should mention that both (externalCall, is defined in a different file) are .sol files that contain Solidity code for a smart-contract and are compiled by truffle before running the test.

I hope one of you can give me some insight in this taking the following function as an example.

File1.sol

```
function Foo (uint _num) external pure returns(bool {
  uint externalResult = externalCall(_num);
  if(externalResult == 15) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

File2.sol

```
function externalCall(uint _num) internal returns(uint) {
    return _num * 2;
}
```

What I would like to stub/mock, is the function externalCall. I would like it to return (for example) 14 every time it is called. I also want to verify that it is called.

I've been searching but have not been able to find anything. I might have overlooked things as all I have is a little background in Java (student). But all I have so far is:

```
it('Should give the right boolean based on the input to the external call.', 

    async () => {
        const testingExService = await ExService.new() // the object to test

      });
```

Comment: where is this externalCall defined? external library?

Comment: Yes. Actually I should mention that it is defined in a different contract as they both are .sol files and are compiled by truffle before running the tests (edited the original post).

Comment: I also changed the example so the functions use Solidity syntax. I didn't realised posting this that this might make a difference because of the compilation step.